# Can I add users to a Gitlab private group with a Webhook?

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

Are account/organization level webhooks a thing in Gitlab? I'm creating a membership site, and when users enroll I'd like to trigger a webhook which adds them to a private Gitlab organization so that they can see all of the group's repositories. Is this possible with Gitlab? All I've been able to find are webhooks at the project level, i.e. when changes are pushed, commits are added, merge requests are started, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#add-a-member-to-a-group-or-project) to add members to projects/groups.

The webhooks you mentioned (changes pushed, merge requests started, etc.) are all events that are triggered within Gitlab and can be used to inform an external service.

The Gitlab API can be used the other way round to allow changes within Gitlab to occur by an external service